# "My friend's, Tom's, object" vs. "My friend, Tom's, object"

Tags: possessives, appositives

How does one combine possession and appositive comma usage in one sentence?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the answer is "You don't."

Comment: I'd agree - the alternatives, such as My friend (Tom) 's bike / My friend (Tom') s bike / My friend's (Tom) bike... are nightmarish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you use the possessive for *friend*? In the first case, the subject is Tom which is modified by *friend*. You would therefore write

> My friend Tom's object.

This sentence:

> My friend's, Tom's object.

makes no sense, especially with that extra comma,  but if you were to try and parse it, the meaning would be:

> My friend has a "Tom's object" and I am referring to it.

You *would* need that comma if you were to write, for example:

> My friend, Tom, has a green car.

Comment: OP is seeing the appositive as a parenthesis (hence the **two** commas) and thus _My friend's bike_ would be the matrix phrase. However, the rule here is as given by Wikipedia:  _[T]he -'s morpheme can be attached finally to noun phrases, even if the head noun does not end the phrase. For example, the phrase_ the king of Spain _can form the possessive_ the king of Spain's, _and the phrase_ the man we saw yesterday _can form_ the man we saw yesterday's.>> Here, 'My friend Tom' is treated as a single noun phrase.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, that’s exactly correct: it’s a clitic that attaches to the entire NP, not to the head noun. Native speakers know this automatically, although for some reason ESL students often get the wrong idea about it. Not sure why.

Comment: There is a difference between “My friend Tom” and “My friend, Tom”. The former is quite unproblematic to add clitics to; the latter impossible (in writing). The real solution is to recast the phrase to avoid having to cliticise it at all: “The bike that belongs to my friend, Tom” or the likes.

Answer (score 3):

My friend Tom's object. ( object can be aim, goal   OR  it could be a material thing)

You don't need commas.

Comment: See Janus Bahs Jacquet's comment.