# The correct placement of the independent clause

Tags: grammar, complex-sentences, independent-clauses

Among these sentences, which one is the correct placement of my brother's name and/or more appropriate in legal documentation?

> I made a bank draft to support my brother’s, **Jason Statham**, higher education.

or

> I made a bank draft to support my brother’s higher education, **Jason Statham**.

or

> I made a bank draft to support my brother’s higher education, **named Jason Statham**.

Comment: I don't think that one "makes a bank draft" is right. You go to the bank and the bank **issues a draft**.  But perhaps you mean something else like a money order. Bank drafts are for buyer-seller relationships. Money orders are purchased and can be cashed by the person to whom you give it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["My friend's, Tom's, object" vs. "My friend, Tom's, object"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124346/my-friends-toms-object-vs-my-friend-toms-object)

Comment: *I made a bank draft to support the higher education of my brother Jason Statham.* Or, if you have only one brother: *I made a bank draft to support the higher education of my brother, Jason Statham.*

Comment: _I made a bank draft to support my brother Jason Statham's education._